# How do I solve this? Fatal error: Class 'WpLatte' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, directory, xampp, ampps

- Wordpress 4.0.6
- XAMPP 1.8.2 [Apache 2.4.4, MySQL 5.5.32, PHP 5.4.25, phpMyAdmin 4.0.4] or AMPPS 2.7
- Theme: Directory 4.18 By AitThemes

I'm working on a backup of an old site from early 2015, however I'm getting the error below. Everything works fine except when I try to load/live view the site content.

The specific file changes depending on what content I try to view. post, category, image-page etc

How do I fix this?

**When trying to view home page:**

`Fatal error: Class 'WpLatte' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\xite\wp-content\themes\directory\page-dir-home.php on line 14`

Line 14 to 19:

```
$latteParams['post'] = WpLatte::createPostEntity(
    $GLOBALS['wp_query']->post,
    array(
        'meta' => $GLOBALS['pageOptions'],
    )
);
```

**- e.g.  When trying to view a post.** `Fatal error: Class 'WpLatte' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\xite\wp-content\themes\directory\single.php on line 2`

Entire code of single.php:

```
<?php
$latteParams['post'] = WpLatte::createPostEntity(
    $GLOBALS['wp_query']->post,
    array(
        'meta' => $GLOBALS['pageOptions'],
    )
);

ob_start();
comments_template('');
ob_get_clean();

/**
 * Fire!
 */
WPLatte::createTemplate(basename(__FILE__, '.php'), $latteParams)->render();
```

**- e.g.  When trying to view a category.** `Fatal error: Class 'WpLatteCategoryEntity' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\xite\wp-content\themes\directory\category.php on line 10`

Entire code of category.php. Line 10 starts $latteParams['category'] = new

```
<?php

/**
 * AIT WordPress Theme
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2012, Affinity Information Technology, s.r.o. (http://ait-themes.club)
 */


$latteParams['category'] = new WpLatteCategoryEntity($wp_query->queried_object);

$latteParams['posts'] = WpLatte::createPostEntity($wp_query->posts);

WPLatte::createTemplate(basename(__FILE__, '.php'), $latteParams)->render();
```

Answer (score 0):

try with a backslash before the class name

```
\WpLatte::createPostEntity
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that before. Found my problem. Theme functions.php wasn't loading.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Wordpress backend was working flawlessly fine, I figured the issue was with the theme.

Found that `wp-content/themes/directory/functions.php` wasn't being loaded. Not sure why.

Switched to the default theme, deleted the Directory theme, re-uploaded it without the functions.php file.
Used Notepad++ to create and save a functions.php file in which I copy-pasted the required code.

Restarted XAMPP, switched back to the Directory theme and everything loaded fine.